# Using an imported image based on json data character name

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am getting data from a json file and when I get the character name of the object i'd like the div to render an image from an image I had imported. But when I use `src={char}` and say for example the char from the json file is 'sage' i'd like to use the sage image. But doing this method does not work like that. Also I am successfully getting the data from the json file so no problems on that end.

Thanks!

```
import sage from '../../assets/images/agents/sage_thumb.webp';
import viper from '../../assets/images/agents/viper_thumb.webp';
import jett from '../../assets/images/agents/jett_thumb.webp';
import valorant_rank from '../../assets/images/ranks/valorant.png';


const renderBody = () => {
        return matchData && matchData.map(({ id, char, name, roundsPlayed, performance, multiKills, team }) => {
            return (
                <tr key={id} className='tr-background'>
                    <td className='match-table__agent-cell'><img className='img-fluid' src={char} alt="" /></td>
                </tr>
            )
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use an object to map the agent name to its image url

```
const imageByAgent = {
  sage: "../../assets/images/agents/sage_thumb.webp",
  viper: "../../assets/images/agents/viper_thumb.webp",
  ...
}
```

And for the image src you can fetch the url using the character name

```
<img className='img-fluid' src={imageByAgent[char]} alt="" />
```